# Is there any difference between copy constructor/copy assignment and normal function call optimization in compiling?

Tags: c++, compilation

I met one interesting compiling error when testing one small example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
   A() { cout <<"A created." <<endl; }
   A(A& a) { cout <<"A created by copy constructor." <<endl; }
   ~A() { cout <<"A destoryed." <<endl; }
};

A CreateObject()
{
    A obj;
    return obj;
}   

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b;

    b= CreateObject();

    return 0;
}
```

it's simple and may not have any issues at all. however, it prompted in compiling:

```
copy_constructor.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
copy_constructor.cpp:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(A)’
copy_constructor.cpp:9: note: candidates are: A::A(A&)
```

it seems that the program tried to call copy constructor when compiling "b= CreateObject();" but there is no matching copy constructor. this should not happen because it just one assignment statement, is there any difference between constructor and normal function in compiling optimization ?

Comment: Compiles for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/019cc3c18ba2a889 . What is your compiler and compilation options?

Comment: The copy constructor should take a `const` reference, not a modifiable one.

Comment: Are you sure your real code isn't actually saying `A b = CreateObject();`?

Comment: Isnt this copy asignment and not copy constructor?

Comment: @Petr Thanks! seems you can compile it well. I use g++ with "g++ a.cpp -o a" to compile the code, but with different result, my compiler information: g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: @Mat that's it! I change the function  `A(A& a){}` to `A(const A& a)`  the code can pass. this is different to @Petr 's test in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/019cc3c18ba2a889. so, should it attribute to the compiler's difference or compilation options ?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, the compiling result for code `A b; b = CreateObject();` and `A b = CreateObject()` are same, actually, I think the compiler will do optimization for `A b; b = CreateObject()`.

Comment: @PeterChan gcc 4.1.2?! Is there any reason for you to use such an old version?

Comment: @Petr, Amazing coincidence here. I happened to chose one older server compile this code example, so this joke occurs, sorry... but thanks you all ! very appreciate:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A(A& a) { cout <<"A created by copy constructor." <<endl; }
...
b = CreateObject();
```

This is invalid according to C++03 standard.

In C++03, `b = CreateObject()` may actually expand to `b = A(CreateObject());`. This has only been "fixed" in later versions of C++, where the creation of the temporary copy is now prohibited.

`CreateObject()` returns a r-hand value which can only be consumed by copy constructor with a `A(const A& a)` signature. Without the `const` modifier, it's only applicable to l-hand values.

E.g. `b = a` would still have been valid with that signature and the expansion, because you would be allowed to modify `a` inside the constructor.

---

This is still replicable setting clang++ to C++98 standard: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c25c469420ab0f

Older versions of Visual-C++ exhibit the precise error shown by the OP.

g++ fails to validate this correctly, even when explictly specifying C++98.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898867/2879325

Comment: you figured the root cause out and indeed I learn a lot from your answer.Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted compiles just fine.  You should however change your copy constructor from `A(A&)` to `A(const A&)`.

Comment: Thanks! @Zwinck, your solution change `A(A&)` to `A(const A&)` really works. I  figured this out with @Ext3h 's interpretation.